# How to create an open class in the build.gradle file?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've been trying to recreate an example from Gradle documentation(https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-tasks/), but something went wrong. It says to add this code to the build.gradle.kts file[image: it says to add this code to the build.gradle.kts file]

But when I tried to type the same thing in my project build.gradle file it won't compile

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename your Gradle file to `build.gradle.kts`

Comment: I don't really understand how to do it, bc it fails build configuration of the app

Comment: You need to convert your Groovy file to Kotlin (build.gradle to build.gradle.kts)

Comment: OR you have to use Groovy language and copy Groovy section.